# Extension not disappears from Edge browser

Tags: powershell, plugins, microsoft-edge, extension

When I remove extension from powershell using remove-appxpackage command (When edge browser was not open) extension is not disappears from edge browser.

This is a command that I have executed.

> get-appxpackage *MyPackageName* | remove-appxpackage

Comment: Did you check if `get-appxpackage MyPackageName` returns no error?

Comment: yes I checked it.. returns no error

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the free utility "CCleaner" and go to the "tools" tab, then click on "browser plugins", choose the Edge browser and click on the extension in question and choose delete.

Answer (score 0):

Issue in Microsoft Edge browser. Raised same issue in Microsoft Edge support site. They replied that : Issue appears to be fixed in our current public stable and newer builds (Edge 16299).

Please follow this link
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/16169364/